# Visual C++ WinForms. When using marshaling occurs: Error C2731 'WinMain': function cannot be overloaded

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, user-interface, c++-cli

I am creating a GUI app in Visual C++, WinForms, Visual Studio 2022

When this library in included `#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>`

The following error appears: `Error C2731   'WinMain': function cannot be overloaded`

The library itself is included for the opportunity to convert from `System::String^` type of a variable into `std::string`
The following solution of string conversion was taken from the user "z05DSL3A" (the answer is at the end of the page).

The problem is that it requires the `#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>` which produces the error

Here's the example of the code where the string conversion is used

```
    #pragma once
    #include <string>
    
    
    #include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h> //The library which causes the error
    
    using namespace System;
    
    
    namespace WebBrowser {
/* ... */

    private: System::Void buttonNavigate_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    
    std::string dot; //Vanialla string

    System::String^ systemString = textNavigate->Text; //Object string

    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::string standardString = context.marshal_as<std::string>(systemString);

    dot = standardString;

    int occurrence = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dot.size(); i++) {
        if (dot[i] == '.') { occurrence++; }
    } 
    
    if (occurrence > 0) {

        webBrowser->Navigate(textNavigate->Text);

    }
    else {
        textNavigate->Text = "Inavlid URL";

    }  }
```

The project mainly consists of 2 files. Here's the full code of these files:

MyForm.cpp:

```
#include "MyForm.h" //Name of the form

using namespace WebBrowser; // Name of the project

[STAThread]
// int WinMain() - compiler returns 0
// void WinMain() - void does not return anything
// WinMain() – entry point for Windows GUI app
int WinMain() {
    //Enable visual elements for the app
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    // Establishing compatability with .NET Framework
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    //Start the app with the form
    Application::Run(gcnew MyForm()); //in cirle brackets () also type the name of the form
    // Application::Run(gcnew Project1::MyForm);
}
```

MyForm.h:

```
  #pragma once
#include <string>


//#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;


namespace WebBrowser {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ buttonBack;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ buttonForward;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textNavigate;
    protected:



    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ buttonNavigate;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowser^ webBrowser;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ buttonRefresh;



    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->buttonBack = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->buttonForward = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textNavigate = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->buttonNavigate = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->webBrowser = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowser());
            this->buttonRefresh = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // buttonBack
            // 
            this->buttonBack->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Verdana", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->buttonBack->Location = System::Drawing::Point(4, 6);
            this->buttonBack->Name = L"buttonBack";
            this->buttonBack->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 25);
            this->buttonBack->TabIndex = 0;
            this->buttonBack->Text = L"<";
            this->buttonBack->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->buttonBack->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::buttonBack_Click);
            // 
            // buttonForward
            // 
            this->buttonForward->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Verdana", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->buttonForward->Location = System::Drawing::Point(35, 5);
            this->buttonForward->Name = L"buttonForward";
            this->buttonForward->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 25);
            this->buttonForward->TabIndex = 1;
            this->buttonForward->Text = L">";
            this->buttonForward->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->buttonForward->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::buttonForward_Click);
            // 
            // textNavigate
            // 
            this->textNavigate->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>(((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Left)
                | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->textNavigate->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Verdana", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->textNavigate->Location = System::Drawing::Point(66, 7);
            this->textNavigate->Name = L"textNavigate";
            this->textNavigate->Size = System::Drawing::Size(440, 23);
            this->textNavigate->TabIndex = 2;
            this->textNavigate->Text = L"Type a URL";
            this->textNavigate->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::textBox1_TextChanged);
            this->textNavigate->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::textBox1_TextChanged);
            this->textNavigate->KeyDown += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventHandler(this, &MyForm::textNavigate_KeyDown);
            this->textNavigate->KeyPress += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler(this, &MyForm::textNavigate_KeyPress);
            // 
            // buttonNavigate
            // 
            this->buttonNavigate->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->buttonNavigate->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Verdana", 9, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->buttonNavigate->Location = System::Drawing::Point(592, 7);
            this->buttonNavigate->Name = L"buttonNavigate";
            this->buttonNavigate->Size = System::Drawing::Size(71, 23);
            this->buttonNavigate->TabIndex = 3;
            this->buttonNavigate->Text = L"Navigate";
            this->buttonNavigate->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->buttonNavigate->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::buttonNavigate_Click);
            // 
            // webBrowser
            // 
            this->webBrowser->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom)
                | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Left)
                | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->webBrowser->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1, 36);
            this->webBrowser->MinimumSize = System::Drawing::Size(20, 20);
            this->webBrowser->Name = L"webBrowser";
            this->webBrowser->ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            this->webBrowser->Size = System::Drawing::Size(662, 425);
            this->webBrowser->TabIndex = 4;
            this->webBrowser->Url = (gcnew System::Uri(L"https://duckduckgo.com", System::UriKind::Absolute));
            this->webBrowser->DocumentCompleted += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this, &MyForm::webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
            // 
            // buttonRefresh
            // 
            this->buttonRefresh->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->buttonRefresh->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Verdana", 9, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->buttonRefresh->Location = System::Drawing::Point(517, 7);
            this->buttonRefresh->Name = L"buttonRefresh";
            this->buttonRefresh->Size = System::Drawing::Size(65, 23);
            this->buttonRefresh->TabIndex = 5;
            this->buttonRefresh->Text = L"Refresh";
            this->buttonRefresh->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->buttonRefresh->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::buttonRefresh_Click);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(666, 456);
            this->Controls->Add(this->buttonRefresh);
            this->Controls->Add(this->webBrowser);
            this->Controls->Add(this->buttonNavigate);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textNavigate);
            this->Controls->Add(this->buttonForward);
            this->Controls->Add(this->buttonBack);
            this->HelpButton = true;
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"FasterThings Web Browser";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs^ e) {
    }
private: System::Void buttonBack_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    webBrowser->GoBack();
}
private: System::Void buttonForward_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    webBrowser->GoForward();
}
private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    if (textNavigate->Text == "Type a URL"|| textNavigate->Text == "Inavlid URL") {
        textNavigate->Text = "";

    }
}
private: System::Void buttonNavigate_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    /* //This is the code that uses string conversion
    std::string dot; //Vanialla string

    System::String^ systemString = textNavigate->Text; //Object string

    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::string standardString = context.marshal_as<std::string>(systemString);

    dot = standardString;

    int occurrence = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dot.size(); i++) {
        if (dot[i] == '.') { occurrence++; }
    } 
    
    if (occurrence > 0) {

        webBrowser->Navigate(textNavigate->Text);

    }
    else {
        textNavigate->Text = "Inavlid URL";

    } */

    webBrowser->Navigate(textNavigate->Text);

}
private: System::Void buttonRefresh_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    webBrowser->Refresh();

}
private: System::Void textNavigate_Leave(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    if (textNavigate->Text == "") {

        textNavigate->Text == "Type a URL";


    }
}
private: System::Void textNavigate_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {
    

}
private: System::Void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs^ e) {
}
private: System::Void textNavigate_KeyDown(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^ e) {

    if (e->KeyValue == (int)Keys::Enter)
    {


        webBrowser -> Navigate(textNavigate->Text);

    }

}
};
}
```

What could be a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you post such an incredible amount of absolutely useless code when the error tells you exactly what the problem is: `Error C2731 'WinMain': function cannot be overloaded`

The problem is obviously on this line:

```
int WinMain()
```

If you read any of the [extensive documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain) on the topic, it should be clear that the function needs to look like this:

```
int WinMain(
  [in] HINSTANCE hInstance,
  [in] HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  [in] LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  [in] int       nShowCmd
);
```